# Want to replace external script http requests (Wordpress site, cant use plugins)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, external, pagespeed

I have a client who is asking for me to solve his issue. He gets errors for external js scripts getting blocked by his ad blocker. Mainly CDN sites.  He wont let us install plugins.

I began to think of a creative solution, and coded up something to store external files locally.(This is done, not asking about storing files)

I was trying to use ob_start() to replace script links in the head tag, but they seem to be loading later, probably aJax, from plugins. I don't know.

Another issue is that some aren't getting loaded inline.
The external javascript files are getting loaded somewhere else.

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this for my client?
would .htaccess redirects redirect the http requests across all activity and solve this issue?

Comment: The problem seems to come frome the client side (the web browser). You have to put the dev mode (F12) and follow the errors in the console and the network tabs

Comment: No, a URL rewrite will not solve this. When the browser makes a request for the CDN URL - then the only one who _could_ rewrite that request, on an HTTP level, would be the CDN server.

Comment: Maybe JavaScript Service Workers can help though, those allow to intercept & manipulate requests the client is about to make.